# Repetir acción mientras ImageView está siendo pulsada

Tags: android, eventos

Buenas, estoy intentando repetir (entrar en bucle) una misma acción siempre que el ImageView esté pulsado (presionado), pero no lo logro, ¿cómo se hace? - La idea es para avanzar un coche arduino a través de peticiones GET, una vez se suelte ('despresione') termina el bucle.

```
    fooImageView = ...;

    fooImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    int contador = 0;
    while (fooImageView.isPressed()) {
        System.out.printf("contador: %d", (++contador));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo detectando los eventos [`ACTION_DOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) y [`ACTION_UP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) y realizar la acción deseada al ocurrir estos.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             Log.d("Arduino auto", "Toco tecla, Avanzaaaaaaaa auto.");
             return true;
          } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             Log.d("Arduino auto", "Libera tecla, Se detiene auto.");
             return true;
          }else{
             //Log.d("Arduino auto", "Evento " + event.getAction() );
             return true;
          }
        }
      });
```

#### Actualización:

Lo que deseas puede realizarse usando un thread y mediante la detección de eventos iniciarlo o detenerlo.

```
  final SomeBackgroundProcess miProceso = new SomeBackgroundProcess();

    miImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                           if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                               Log.d("Arduino auto", "Toco tecla, Inicia auto.");
                                               miProceso.start();
                                               return true;
                                           } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                               miProceso.stop();
                                               Log.d("Arduino auto", "Libera tecla, Se detiene auto.");
                                               return true;
                                           }else{
                                               return true;
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
```

Esta será la clase usada la cual al estar en ejecución el thread puedes crear un loop infinito, que sera detenido cuando levantes la tecla que a su ves indica al thread detenerse. Agrego un sleep para evitar bloquear la aplicación, tu puedes reducir la cantidad de milisegundos entre cada llamada.

```
public class SomeBackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

    Thread backgroundThread;
    private int counter;

    public void start() {
        if (backgroundThread == null) {
            backgroundThread = new Thread(this);
            backgroundThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (backgroundThread != null) {
            backgroundThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread starting.");
            while (!backgroundThread.interrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                // doSomething();
                Log.d("Arduino auto", "Auto en movimiento. " + ++counter);
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread stopping.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
        } finally {
            backgroundThread = null;
        }
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entiendo, y agradezco la respuesta, pero, aplico el código que me has proporcionado, lo intento realizar en 'bucle mientras sea MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN' pero no es posible, no lo logro, como puedo realizar la acción en bucle?

Comment: He agregado un update de mi respuesta, lo que agrego es regularmente lo que se usa cuando quieren activar o desactivar la ejecución de un proceso.